# MySQL - Unable to enable binary logging

Tags: mysql, mysql-replication, ubuntu-14.04, binary-log

I'm trying to enable binary logging so that I can set up master-slave replication between two servers. I'm working with an existing server with lots of data and I'm trying to dump the data with the following command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p --all-databases --master-data > masterdump.sql
```

but I get the error: `mysqldump: Error: Binlogging on server not active`.

I've followed all sorts of tutorials on how to enable binary logging, but nothing has worked. I've made sure that I've added the following parameters to my.cnf:

```
server-id    = 1
log_bin      = /var/log/mysql/mysql-bin.log
sync_binlog  = 1
```

When I restart MySQL, it takes a while (I assume it's due to the huge size of the database), about 60 seconds, but eventually starts. However, when I check `/var/log/mysql/error.log`, I find the following error (duplicated hundreds of times):

```
InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1, error: 11
InnoDB: Check that you do not already have another mysqld process
```

So I went looking for all the mysqld processes by running `pstree` and I found the following:

```
root@my_server:~# pstree
init---some stuff
     |--
     |--mysqld---10*[{mysqld}]
     |--
     |--sudo---mysqld---23*[{mysqld}]
```

This is where I'm stuck. I don't know whether it's normal to have `mysqld` AND `sudo mysqld` both running. The server is being maintained by [ServerPilot](http://serverpilot.io), which [I think] installed MySQL for me.

Does any of this evidence point to any sort of reason why Binary Logging won't enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the multiple mysqld processes were causing problems. Thanks to some tips from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6481337/752878) I was able to kill the process tree under `sudo mysqld` and Binary logging started right away. Getting the rest of master-slave replication working was pretty quick after that, thanks to [this awesome tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JXDuVypcHNA).